# star uml: C# code forward / reverse engineer

Tags: c#, uml

Has any one tried forward/reverse C# code generation? what has been your experience? is it worth it? Or is it just good for UML diagrams

Comment: What do you mean: "is it worth it?" Depends on your plans...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that StarUML hasn't been updated for ages (latest version released at 2005). I wouldn't trust it for code generation, especially if newer versions of C# are used.

Answer (score 0):

In a previous contract, we used Maven & AndroMDA (a plugin) to generate code and database schema from a UML model for sizeable multi tiered enterprise level projects. It worked well. I can't quite recall which UML designer we used, but I think it may have been magic draw.

I've also used Enterprise Architect, but it feels a lot more cludgy, and in my experience takes quite a bit of tweaking before it generates good code, or even code that compiles. You'd probably need to invest in some proper training if you were going to go the EA route.